# LMS1xx node is not available now?

Tags: sicklms

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is LMS1xx node still available on [link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/LMS1xx) now? I was told this:"Cannot load information on name: LMS1xx, distro: fuerte, which means that it is not yet in our index. Please see this page for information on how to submit your repository to our index." Does someone has this node copy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47619/lms1xx-node-is-not-available-now?/) by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [this](http://www.ist.tugraz.at/robotics/bin/viewfile/Main/LaserDevice?rev=1;filename=laser_driver_sick_lms1xx.zip) is the node copy you are finding.

Additional reference:

https://github.com/konradb3/RCPRG-ros-pkg/tree/master/RCPRG_laser_drivers

https://github.com/konradb3/RCPRG-ros-pkg/wiki/LMS1xx
http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/api/LMS1xx/html/files.html
http://www.ist.tugraz.at/robotics/bin/view/Main/LaserDevice

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1